# Is there an easy way to set headers on my entire S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I want to set `Cache-Control` headers on my static assets (all my UI images) so they get cached by users' browsers. Is there a GUI tool that will let me do this or will I have to use the S3 API to list all objects and the copy/replace them all with the new headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Bucket Explorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/) or [Cloudberry Explorer](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-amazon-s3-explorer-cloudfront-IAM.aspx) to do this.

They will still need to do each file behind the scenes so it might take some time if you have lots of files, but at least you will not have to manually do each file.